# Server 500 error occurs always

Tags: php, html, mysql, curl

```
<?php

   $dbhost = 'xx';
   $dbuser = 'xx';
   $dbpass = 'xxxx';

   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
   if(! $conn )
   {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   mysql_select_db('url') or trigger_error("Unable to switch to the database: " . mysql_error()); 


function arr($num){

$ch = curl_init();
$r= rand (1,90);
$url="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=Gravity%20Falls%20Latest%20images&num=10&start=".$r."&safe=off&cx=x:2hdsc4__avm&filter=0&c2coff=disable&alt=json&key=x";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

        $a=intval($num);
        $data = json_decode($output, true);
        $se= $data['items'][$a]['pagemap']['cse_image'][0]['src'];

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT `url` FROM `url` WHERE `url`='".$se."'");

  if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)
  {
     $rr= rand (1,10);
     arr($rr);
  }else{

      mysql_query("INSERT INTO `url`(`url`) VALUES ('".$se."')");
      return $se;

      }
}

$rr= rand (1,10);
echo arr($rr);





require_once("src/facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'x';
$config['secret'] = 'x';
$config['fileUpload'] = true;
$fb = new Facebook($config);

$params = array(
"access_token" => "xxx",
"message" => "",
"url" => "".arr($rr)."", 
);

try {

$ret=$fb->api('/1111/photos', 'POST', $params);
echo 'Photo successfully uploaded to Facebook Album';
}
catch(Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

I have tried this on 5 to 6 servers and all gives me `500 error` but when i remove sql connection it works! I have supplied all correct mysql information .

Then why its showing 500?

**Edit:**

- If I comment out

  ```
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT `url` FROM `url` WHERE `url`='".$se."'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)
  {
   $rr= rand (1,10);
   arr($rr);
   }else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `url`(`url`) VALUES ('".$se."')");
    return $se;

    }
  ```

It works!

Comment: you are missing a `'` on line 3. `$dbhost = 'x;` should be `$dbhost = 'x';`

Comment: ...that's probably just a typo. ^^^ - yet nowadays, one never knows.

Comment: 500 error = something blew up. Look in your server's error logs for details about the 500. and like chriz said, you've got a typo with the missing `'`, which is probably killing your script outright with a fatal parse error.

Comment: @chriz One guy got eager to make it an answer lol - I "never". Edit: Yep, typo.

Comment: Personally, after the second or third server, I probably would have started to consider that maybe it was the code, not the hardware, that was the issue...

Comment: @chriz Still not fixed!

Comment: @AnthonyGrist What code problem?

Comment: Try `mysql_select_db('url', $conn)` - make sure both DB and table are `url`, that's not the usual method but hey... if that's what it is, then that's what it is. Check your logs.

Comment: @testrtq I don't even know PHP, I'm just here because you tagged the question with Javascript and there are some issues with it. What do your server's error logs say?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Still 500 no errors

Comment: @testrtq Maybe try rewriting the connection code so it is more modern, using `mysqli` instead of `mysql` as `mysql` is depreciated. [this](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) is a very good tutorial to help start you out

Comment: @chriz if i comment out CURL part it works fine, so what is curl problem

Comment: add `if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo curl_error($ch);
      }` because if curl have some error you can't do this `$data = json_decode($output, true);
        $se= $data['items'][$a]['pagemap']['cse_image'][0]['src'];
`

Comment: take a look at your `url` table. The way you are calling your `arr` function recursively there is a chance of an endless recursion if you only get `$se` url values that are already stored in that table.

Comment: Not the solution to your problem, but you should also look at optimizing your query with the "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" query. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @cypherabe You solved it, i received no response from $url thus i was stuck in loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at your `url` table. The way you are calling your `arr` function recursively there is a chance of an endless recursion if you only get `$se` url values that are already stored in that table. (also if you get a value that gets cast to an empty string)